# Scheme: pattern matching syntax

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, syntax-error, racket

I need to be able to match patterns like this:

```
(lambda (<param> ...) <stmt> ...)
```

using match-lambda and return something like this:

```
(CLOSURE ENV '(<param> ...) (λ (ENV) <stmt> ...)
```

where the list of parameters is quoted.

The closest I can get is:

```
(`(lambda (,<param> . ,<params>) . ,<stmts>) 
 `(CLOSURE ENV (,<param> . <params>) (lambda (ENV) (,@<stmts>))))
```

For instance, '(lambda (ls1 ls2) (append ls1 ls2))) returns:

```
'(CLOSURE
  ENV
  (ls1 ls2)
  (lambda (ENV) ((append ls1 ls2))))
```

but I can't get the parameter list to be quoted.

In answers to previous posts I have been told that the "." in the pattern must precede the last element in a list.  However I have found that this isn't correct.  For instance:

```
(define function-call
  (match-rewriter
   (`(,<func> . ,<args>)
    `(CALL ,<func> (list ,@<args>)))) (+ 1 2) )
```

returns:

```
'(CALL + (list 1 2))
```

where args has clearly match both the 1 and the 2.

If anyone can give me some advice on how to fix this pattern it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hiya; regarding your comment about (my comment about) the placement of the dot: the point is that the dot must precede at most one element *of the pattern*, as it does here.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks for following up with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `'` literally into the output.  This can be tricky when using `quasiquote`, so I'll avoid that in my answer.  Here's the pattern and right-hand side you want:

```
[`(lambda (,<param> . ,<params>) . ,<stmts>)
 (list 'CLOSURE 'ENV (list 'quote (cons <param> <params>)) 
       (list 'lambda '(ENV) <stmts>))]
```

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I thought I had to use the quasiquote in the pattern match and inserting the quote myself was getting me nowhere.